# Barra de rolagem horizontal no sublime text3, como ativar?

Tags: cakephp, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

Eu uso o Sublime text 3 nos meus projetos  em cakePHP. Por padrão os arquivos html no cake tem a extensão .ctp e quando eu preciso mexer em um arquivo .ctp onde eu tenho uma linha de código muito grande ele da uma quebra de linha ao invés de me dar a opção de uma barra de rolagem horizontal como é feito com os arquivos .PHP

Alguém aí sabe o que eu posso fazer pra habilitar a barra de rolagem para arquivos com extensão .CTP?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queria comentar, mas não tenho permissão.

Acesse o menu `VIEW` e desative a opção `WORD WRAP`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou você pode definir `"word_wrap": false,` no seu arquivo de configurações do sublime `Settings - User` (Preferences.sublime-settings).

Exemplificando como ficaria:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 11,
    "word_wrap": false,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
    ]
}
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, deu certo aqui. Daqui a 10 minutos eu aceito a sua resposta.